# IPTABLES -L OPTION NOT SHOWING SNAT RULE

Tags: iptables, nat

I am able to get NAT to work using the following snat rule:

```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em2 -j SNAT --to 192.168.2.2
```

My question is:
Why is this rule not displayed when I issue the command:

```
   iptables -L
```

or even

```
   iptables -L -v
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iptables -L -t nat` is what you're looking for.

As you specify the table when you add the rule, you have to specify it to see it.

Comment: Is there any way to list ALL rules?

Comment: @Samir Sure. There are 5 tables (filter,nat,mangle,raw,security). You call `iptables -L -t table` for each. ;-)