# Ubuntu 16 server cannot access it's own port 80

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, node.js

When I listen on port 80 with NodeJS v10 all other machines can access the port but the machine itself cannot. This is very strange, and is the same for loopback and the eth0 IP address. However, it can access port 90 on itself just fine as can the other machines on the network.

I've used a simple hello world app to verify that the NodeJS script is not at fault.

This also occurs in NodeJS 12.13.0, so I don't think Node is the problem at all.

`iptables -L` says everything is empty with policy ACCEPT.

`netstat -tulpn` lists no port 80 except the one I'm testing with.

Comment: Normally, isn't node suppose to listen on :3000? You then send/proxy to webserver port :80 as needed. You don't mention a web server, or it's config. You sure webserver is delivering the app correctly?

Comment: If using as nodejs as simple server, do you have anything else running on port 80?

Comment: If anything else was running, `netstat -tulpn` should list it, right?

Comment: try `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":80\ "` without node running. You see a 'LISTEN'? Try again with it running. It should be listening to all interfaces for what you want. Not a specific IP or network.

Answer (score 2):

I found this line in `/etc/rc.local`.

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Problem found!

This answer says why the rule did not show up in `iptables -L`: https://serverfault.com/a/685948/32875.

> There are 5 tables (filter,nat,mangle,raw,security). You call `iptables -L -t table` for each.

Answer (score 0):

It's could be because if you want to use port 80, you need sudo permissions for open it.

Comment: But the other machines on the network wouldn't be able to access it either then.

Comment: perhaps config files are let in you only localhost connection, you could change a subnet IP instead of localhost